# Salesforce community: Custom VF page for an object

Tags: community, custom

I have a requirement in community. If a community user loges in he should see the custom VF page for an object say Accounts object  and if a user loges into salesforce he should see the standard salesforce page for Account object. Can any one suggest me how i can achieve this.

Thanks,
IRaj

Answer (score 0):

yep. This can be done. you just need to include those VF pages as per your requirement into the Profile of that particular user. Hope thi helps out a bit. u also need to set appropiate Vf pages to the page layouts

Comment: You should explain a bit more on how exactly you suggest to do it. Please add some steps, clickpath, a screenshot, name the setting in the profile or whatever.